# Paypal: Is there any way to make PayPal ExpressCheckout in Arabic Language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, express-checkout

I'm just searching a week to figure out how to make this page (below attached image) in Arabic? Although I came to know that paypal don't have `LOCALECODE` for Arabic Language. Is there any way to skip this page or make it in Arabic? Or whole paypal transaction inside my website without not redirecting Sandbox? Any resource or reference would be a lot help for me.

Also, I'm working on Ruby on Rails application.

Thanks. 
[image: Paypal ExpressCheckout login page]

Answer (score 0):

These are the current languages supported by PayPal express checkout.  Also keep in mind this link has all the countries that PayPal supports. Hope this helps:
https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/country-worldwide

```
AT language_0 de_DE
AT language_1 en_US
AU language_0 en_AU
BE language_0 en_US
BE language_1 nl_NL
BE language_2 fr_FR
C2 language_0 en_US
C2 language_1 zh_XC
C2 language_2 fr_XC
C2 language_3 es_XC
CH language_0 de_DE
CH language_1 fr_FR
CH language_2 en_US
CN language_0 zh_CN
default language_0 en_US
default language_1 fr_XC
default language_2 es_XC
default language_3 zh_XC
DE language_0 de_DE
DE language_1 en_US
ES language_0 es_ES
ES language_1 en_US
FR language_0 fr_FR
FR language_1 en_US
GB language_0 en_GB
GF language_0 fr_FR
GF language_1 en_US
GI language_0 en_US
GP language_0 fr_FR
GP language_1 en_US
IE language_0 en_US
IT language_0 it_IT
IT language_1 en_US
JP language_0 ja_JP
JP language_1 en_US
MQ language_0 fr_FR
MQ language_1 en_US
NL language_0 nl_NL
NL language_1 en_US
PL language_0 pl_PL
PL language_1 en_US
RE language_0 fr_FR
RE language_1 en_US
US language_0 en_US
US language_1 fr_XC
US language_2 es_XC
US language_3 zh_XC
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But we need it in 'Arabic' language. And I'm afraid there is no localecode for Arabic.

Comment: Exactly what I'm saying, Paypal doesn't support Arabic, therefore you can not do it.  Therefore this question is solved :D you might want to look at a different payment solution

Comment: Could you please suggest me what's the alternative payment gateway to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is out of date. It appears that PayPal now offers Arabic. 
https://www.paypal.com/eg/webapps/mpp/sign-up-arabic